# Почему display портит transition?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css3

Есть 2 `div`

```
<din class="div1"></din>
<din class="div2"></din>
```

css:

```
.div1 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.div2 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
}

.active {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

Для надежности (старые браузеры) я по мимо `opacity` добавляю ещё и `display: none;`, но это ломает анимацию и блок появляется резко, как такое исправить?

http://jsfiddle.net/sqjr1dvy/

Comment: убрать display:none; старые браузеры переживут, поверь

Answer (score 1):

Анимация не работает со свойством display, используйте другие свойства, например visibility и opacity.

Comment: Но ведь transition относится только к opacity, я же не пишу transition: all, что ему не нравится?